# WP7 SDK: Is it possible to set camera focus mode to macro?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

It it possible to set camera focus mode to macro?

Answer (score 4):

As I can  see in [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.devices.photocamera%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) - there is no API for it.